# Can't build for 60 seconds (LNK1104)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Started a new, empty VC++ project in Visual Studio 2015 with default settings (like hundreds of times before), and a new problem occurs:

After building, running, and closing a program, LINK can't open the .exe file for writing, until 60 sec. after closing the program (LNK1104).

Of course, an exe file can not be opened for writing while an image is loaded, but that should not be the case here.  The process disappears promptly from Task Manager as soon as the program is closed.

Also, any attempt to rebuild the program (without running it) before 60 seconds seems to reset the "timer."  If I keep trying every 30 seconds it will never succeed.  After waiting 60 seconds, it works every time.

This is my entire source code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE inst, HINSTANCE prev, char *cmd, int show)
{ return 0; }
```

I have restarted Windows and VS to no avail.

New info: I looked for the .exe file in the Release folder (or Debug, same thing) and it wasn't there!  (The other usual build files were there.)  After building the program, the .exe file appeared.  After running and closing it, 44 seconds later, it vanished!

P.S.  it only vanishes if I attempt to rebuild it within 60 seconds and get LNK1104.  Then after 44 sec, it disappears.

I also deleted it manually before the 60 sec. was up, then I could rebuild right away.

Visual Studio Community 2015 V 14.0.25123.00 Update 2, was working fine a week ago.

Comment: What anti-virus software are you using?

Comment: Security Essentials & MBAM

Comment: Have you excluded your development directories from real-time scans? This sounds like AV interference. Avast!, for instance, delayed execution start when a new .exe was created until it was finished scanning it, which took more than 30 seconds.

Comment: Well, ok... but it was all right 5 days ago and I haven't changed anything.  And I hope it doesn't take 30 seconds to scan {return 0;}!

Comment: Suit yourself. I offered a suggestion as to something for you to check into as a possible solution. I'm not forcing you to do so. Good luck.

Comment: Tried turning off Security Essentials, no difference.

Comment: BTW there is no perceptible execution delay when new exe created.  It runs immediately after build.  This problem happens after it has already run.  Also, MBAM real-time protection is already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Summary of problem:
After building and running a program, it can not be built again until a minute or two elapses (linker error LNK1104, can not open the .exe file for writing).
After this time delay, the linker will succeed.  It can be observed that the .exe file disappears by itself after this delay.

The solution is: start the Application Experience Service, which

> Processes application compatibility cache requests for applications as they are launched.

After starting the service, it can be disabled again.  Evidently after processing "cache requests" it is no longer needed.

No explanation was found as to why this happens.  Other users have had this happen for no apparent reason.

Users who leave the Service running all the time will probably never notice the problem.